# Keep getting "Array" from fetching decoded JSON data?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, mysqli

When I encode the json data fetching from the mysql database, I get this:

`[{"userid":"11","postid":"12"},{"userid":"13","postid":"12"},{"userid":"16","postid":"12"}]`

And I am trying to get only the userid's like this: `11, 13, 16`.

Decoding the json data gives me an output of: `Array`. And nothing else. When I `var_dump` this is my results:

```
array(3) { 
        [0]=> array(2) { 
                    ["userid"]=> string(2) "11" 
                    ["postid"]=> string(2) "12" 
                } 
        [1]=> array(2) { 
                    ["userid"]=> string(2) "13" 
                    ["postid"]=> string(2) "12" 
                } 
        [2]=> array(2) { 
                    ["userid"]=> string(2) "16" 
                    ["postid"]=> string(2) "12" 
                }
```

So I know there is data present, it's just not showing for some reason.

Here is what my query looks like:

```
if(isset($_POST['postuserid'])){
    $uid = $_POST['postuserid'];

    $ssql = "SELECT * FROM foodid WHERE postid=$uid"; 
    $rresult = mysqli_query($db,$ssql); 
    while ($lrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rresult)){ 
        $ret[] = $lrow;
        $postjson = json_encode($ret);  
        $decode_postid = json_decode($postjson, true);
        $new_postid = $decode_postid;
    } 
    var_dump($new_postid);
    die($new_postid);
    // die($new_postid['userid']); is what I need along with all data userid fetched.

}
```

Is there a reason why this works when I encode json data, but not when I decode the json data?

Comment: `$new_postid` is being loaded in a while loop, but you are over writing it each time round the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to get that array out of the die function? It can only take a string or int.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Your array is there... just do something like:

```
$ids = '';
foreach ($new_postid as $post) {
    $ids .= $post['userid'] . ',';
}
$ids = rtrim($ids,',');
die($ids);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try mapping those results:

```
$new_postid = $decode_postid;
$new_postid = array_map(function($item){
    return $item['userid'];
}, $new_postid);

var_dump($new_postid);
```

Output

> array(3) {
>     [0]=>
>     string(2) "11"
>     [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)=>
>     string(2) "13"
>     [2]=>
>     string(2) "16"
>   }

If you need to output as string, just use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function

```
die(implode(',',$new_postid));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: Thank you, that's what I got, but I was expecting these results with `die($new_postid)`: 11, 13, 16. Just the numbers

Comment: No problem. IMO it's better when using language construction. The code becomes cleaner and easier to mantain. Avoid substrings and loops if you have a better way to do.

Comment: I agree! Also with this I plan one convert the numbers into names. I.E. "Billy" with take the place of "11". I have to think of some way to do that with php query tables.

Comment: I have one more question, say If i wanted the `postid` as well. Would I do the same thing here and just change the variable names?